# UWP ListView without DataBinding

Tags: listview, data-binding, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I'm just getting started with UWP and I'm currently trying to create a ListView with items.
I've seen a few tutorials, but all tutorials work with DataBinding.

Is there a way to create a ListView without DataBinding? DataBinding is awesome for simple models, but when it gets complicated I prefer to fill the view myself. Like loading images from an url, date to string and those kind of things.

Is this possible? (If I'm totally looking at this the wrong way also please correct me)

**Edit**

This is how I fill a list on Android:

- I have a list of items (for example Person with a firstName and lastName).
- I have a layout for a single list item (for example just a textBlock)
- I have a ViewHolder which holds references to the views in a single list item (for example the textBlock). This ViewHolder gets reused.
- I have an Adapter which gives the information to the ListView (like number of items and creating ViewHolders and binding the data to the ViewHolder)
- When binding the data to the ViewHolder I get full flexibility on how I want to do it. I have a reference to every View in the list item. So for example I can fill the textBlock with firstName and lastName combined (this is all done in the code instead of the layout file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So allow me to preface this with, you're 100% wrong about databinding lol... The more complex things get, the more DataBinding is useful. In fact, it's actually the opposite that is true. People tend to find the MVVM process and Databinding to be a bit robust for simple examples.

That said....

Here is how to do what you're asking.

In order to add an item to your list view you simply need to call `Items.Add`

In my Xaml I have a `ListView` named TestListview

```
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="TestListview"/>
</Grid>
```

In my behind code (the Xaml.cs) I have the following in my constructor.

```
TestListview.Items.Add("Item One");
TestListview.Items.Add("Item Two");
TestListview.Items.Add("Item Three");
```

That's it. Now items will be in my listview. Once again, this is the worst way to do this, isn't maintainable, is a poor practice to learn and would get you chastised, tared and feathered as a professional.

Good luck!

### Update

Per OP's request, here is an example as to why life is horrible without databinding

We're going to explore two examples. In our first example, we are going to look at how to populate a listview with an object that has a few properties on it. Then we are going to enable a detailed view of that object when it's clicked.

Then in our second example we will see how to accomplish the same thing with only databinding.

For both examples I will be using this dummy data generator and model

```
   public static IEnumerable<PersonModel> GenerateFakePeople()
   {
            List<PersonModel> people = new List<PersonModel>();
            people.Add(new PersonModel() { FirstName = "Aaron", LastName = "Doe", Age = 11, Bio = "This is a short bio bio bio blah blah blah.", ImageURL= "http://media.boingboing.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/breadingcats.jpg" });
            people.Add(new PersonModel() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", Age = 21, Bio = "This is a short bio bio bio blah blah blah.", ImageURL = "http://media.boingboing.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/breadingcats.jpg" });
            people.Add(new PersonModel() { FirstName = "David", LastName = "Doe", Age = 31, Bio = "This is a short bio bio bio blah blah blah.", ImageURL = "http://media.boingboing.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/breadingcats.jpg" });
            return people;
    }

    public class PersonModel
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string ImageURL { get; set; }
        public string Bio { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see in the xaml I have expanded it out to include a place to display our user that has been clicked on.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="TestListview" Grid.Column="0" SelectionChanged="TestListview_SelectionChanged"/>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="PersonsImage" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock x:Name="PersonsName" FontSize="25"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PersonsAge" FontSize="25"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PersonsBio" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="30" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

In our behind code you can see how the information is not only populated on the screen but also the highly coupled work that takes place to create each individual UI item.

When we tightly couple UI elements together like this, it makes it very difficult to change the UI without breaking things. Not only that it makes it difficult to change the model as well.

For example, if I wanted to change my PersonModel object to support a full name instead of first and last, I would have to go through and change every single line of code that had the first name property referenced.

To make matters worse, if I added in a full name property but decided to leave the first name and last name properties, but wanted to switch them out, I would have to manually go through and find all the spots that referenced the old properties.

Oh, and how do I access the bio? We are capturing the selection changed event from the ListView but we are only able to access the data from the UI Elements because we never actually tied the PersonModel to the ListViewItem.

Finally, updating the screen, this is probably the biggest selling point of data binding. What happens if for some reason I modify in the code the name of someone, I change their age, their bio or some other property attached to them? I would have to go through the UI and manually update every single spot that property is referenced. Which means I have to track every place it's referenced. This is highly coupled and a very poor design.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        
    public MainWindow()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        
        foreach(PersonModel person in GenerateFakePeople())
        {
            TestListview.Items.Add(GenerateItem(person));
        }
    }

  
    public static StackPanel GenerateItem(PersonModel person)
    {
        StackPanel outerStackPanel = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
        StackPanel innerStackPanel = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
        Image image = new Image() { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(person.ImageURL)) };
        TextBlock firstName = new TextBlock() { Text = person.FirstName };
        TextBlock lastName = new TextBlock() { Text = person.LastName };
        TextBlock age = new TextBlock() { Text = person.Age.ToString() };
        TextBlock bio = new TextBlock() { Text = person.Bio };

        outerStackPanel.Children.Add(image);
        outerStackPanel.Children.Add(innerStackPanel);
        innerStackPanel.Children.Add(firstName);
        innerStackPanel.Children.Add(lastName);
        innerStackPanel.Children.Add(age);

        return outerStackPanel;
    }

    private void TestListview_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        StackPanel outerStackPanel = (sender as ListView).SelectedItem as StackPanel;

        if (outerStackPanel != null)
        {
            Image image = outerStackPanel.Children[0] as Image;
            StackPanel innerStackPanel = outerStackPanel.Children[1] as StackPanel;

            if (innerStackPanel != null)
            {
                TextBlock firstName = innerStackPanel.Children[0] as TextBlock;
                TextBlock lastName = innerStackPanel.Children[1] as TextBlock;
                TextBlock age = innerStackPanel.Children[2] as TextBlock;
               // TextBlock bio = innerStackPanel.Children[3] as TextBlock;

                PersonsImage.Source = image.Source;
                PersonsName.Text = firstName.Text + " " + lastName.Text;
                PersonsAge.Text = age.Text;
             //   PersonsBio.Text = bio.Text; //Cant Even access the bio! It doesn't exist!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now let's look at the data binding example.

With DataBinding we have the power of simplifying our behind code. It allows us to use patterns such as MVVM. Which are EXTRAORDINARILY powerful when working on a large scale.

Here is our new Xaml file

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="PeopleListView" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageURL}" Height="100" Width="100"/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width=".3*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=PeopleListView, Path=SelectedItem.ImageURL}"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=PeopleListView, Path=SelectedItem.FirstName}"  FontSize="25"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=PeopleListView, Path=SelectedItem.Age}" FontSize="25"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=PeopleListView, Path=SelectedItem.Bio}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="30" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

As you can see a few things changed. The first thing that you should notice is that the ListView now has an ItemTemplate. This says that for every item that is added to the ListView, this is how you want it displayed in the control. This allows us to keep all of the UI design stuff in the xaml where it belongs.

The second thing you should notice is that I am now binding our person display area to the ListView's SelectedItem property. This allows us to access the actual data object directly instead of having to dig through controls. This is a far superior way of dealing with data.

Finally lets have a look at our CS now

```
    private ObservableCollection<PersonModel> _people;

    public ObservableCollection<PersonModel> People
    {
        get { return _people; }
        set { _people = value; }
    }


    public MainWindow()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        People = new ObservableCollection<PersonModel>(GenerateFakePeople());
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
```

As you can see clearly, our CS is greatly simplified. Not only that, we can operate on our objects and we can keep our UI in sync by firing a PropertyChangedEvent off. This would update everything that binds to a property. We can also easily add more PersonModel's to our People collection and it will be reflected on the screen as well.

I understand your apprehension to DataBinding and the MVVM architecture. I promise you though that the entire community isn't wrong. We are building upon decades of learning from bad practices. MVVM provides businesses a very modular and cost effective way of building software. It allows you to reuse code easily and most importantly, if something breaks, it is easy to find because you don't need to search your code for a million references to a property. You just fix it once.

I highly encourage you to do a little research on MVVM, DataBinding and Object Oriented Programming. Get out there and actually build some phone apps or software that you will be required to maintain. Then, when you have to spend an hour updating code because you changed the text of something, you'll understand.

Here are some resources I would look into. Don't be scared off if they say WPF and not UWP. For these topics the patterns are almost identical.

[What is MVVM?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx)

[What is DataBinding?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Creating User Controls](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_custom_controls.htm)

[Creating Lookless Controls](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1056014/WPF-Lookless-Controls)

Comment: Why does it become more useful? You post a very simple example, but I don't see why it becomes more useful when things get more complex. Could you show a more complex example of DataBinding?

Comment: Yeah let me get into the office and I'll cook one up for you. I promise you it does.

Comment: Thanks for the example! I definitely don't want to add all the views without reusing those views. Although I understand DataBinding and MVVM better now and understand why it could be very useful, I still think I can run into issues. I made an Android app recently where the list items could expand. Could this also be solved using DataBinding? I've also updated my question with what I'm used to on Android, so you can better understand what I mean.

Comment: @KevinvanMierlo I hate to be a dick but Android, Java and XML are NOT NOT NOT UWP, WPF, C# or XAML. They look the same but they are not the same. If you're going to explore C# and XAML then I suggest you put your Android experience to the side. Otherwise your cup is already full and you can't learn what you need to in order to write professional looking code.

Comment: That's not where I'm getting at, I know they are very different and these are two different platforms. I'll use DataBinding because that's the way to go, and I'm trying to understand the best way to handle things on UWP. But what I am getting at is how to handle complex situations. Like the expanding of list items. If all these things can be done with DataBinding, great! If not I'd like to know how to handle it otherwise.

Comment: Expanding isn't handled with DataBinding at all. DataBinding just connects your Data layer (your ViewModel) to your UI which is your View. The expanding is handled by your view. If your view model is telling the UI to do anything at all then you're doing it wrong.Notice that in my DataBinding example, the c# only cares about the PersonModel. It doesn't tell the UI how to look. It doesn't tell the Listview how to display. It doesn't tell it what to display. It just cares about Data.

Comment: I understand that. And that's what I'm trying to figure out. I don't have a reference to a view in the ListView. So how can I get a reference to the view so it can handle the expansion?

Comment: I would start with something simple. Here is what you need to research. #1 Create a real MVVM project and have something simple data bind to the screen.  #2 Research how to create a custom user control #3 Research how to create a custom Lookless control. #4 Research how to template things. If you do this in this order then you'll be able to make your Expander control. If you don't learn these things then you will continue to ask unanswerable questions because in order to make it you require other knowledge.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed to know. If you could update your answer I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there are really not so many case when you would not want to use data binding. The performance penalty is not so big as it used to be before the introduction of x:Bind. Other than that, you can do things like date formatting you mention using converters.

If I have a really complicated item that can render in many ways, I use a UserControl. I just bind the data object to a property on the UserControl and handle everything in the code-behind of the of this UserControl.

Comment: Could you show me an example of the converter and the usercontrol? Because these things happen a lot in my projects and I don't know how one should handle this.

Comment: Converter (WPF, but the principle is the same): http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html and a UserConrol is just a UserControl

Comment: Do you also have one for UserControl? I still don't really understand why DataBinding would be easier than just adding it in code with these complex items.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you are totally wrong! :-)

Create an instance of List, where MyItem is the same class that you want to add manually to the ListView (the same that you add to the Items property of the ListView). At the end you have a List with a lot of objects.

Then you can simply:

```
this.listView1.ItemsSource = your_instance_of_list
```

Done! After that you need to set an ItemTemplate.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I'm looking for ways to add complex things to my view. Another example: I got a base64 encoded string which needs to be decoded into an image. You can't really use databinding for this

Comment: Please, read about data-binding and converter, and you discover a lot of interesting things.

Comment: I just did some reading about it and this could be used for my example. But there are more examples in which I have doubts about the DataBinding. For example loading an image from an url, with showing a placeholder and error view if the loading fails. Do you have an idea how to solve that?

Comment: Create a custom UserControl for showing images and bind the mage url to it

Comment: Hmm that could work and solve most of my problems. Have you ever done the binding in code or is that something you shouldn't want?